# How to set camera focus value manually in Android

Tags: android, android-camera

I intend to create an application that can take photos in the following way:

- When the user touches the screen, it starts to take *photos*
- It takes several photos within a few microseconds, each with *different focus*

In pseudocode:

```
Camera camera = getAndroidCamera();
for(i<10)
{
  camera.setFocus(i*0.1);
  camera.takePhoto(path, pictureName+i);
}
```

So basically I intend to take photos of the same object with different values of focus.

According to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2042/can-i-manually-focus-the-camera-on-my-android-phone), it is not possible, only *assisted autofocus* is viable.

Can you confirm it?

If possible, how should I do it? Should I [set autofocus to different areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968132/set-the-camera-focus-area-in-android)?

Answer (score 0):

Answer -- [Android setFocusArea and Auto Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460647/android-setfocusarea-and-auto-focus)

All I had to do is cancel previously called autofocus. Basically the correct order of actions is this:

```
protected void focusOnTouch(MotionEvent event) {
    if (camera != null) {

        camera.cancelAutoFocus();
        Rect focusRect = calculateTapArea(event.getX(), event.getY(), 1f);
        Rect meteringRect = calculateTapArea(event.getX(), event.getY(), 1.5f);

        Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
        parameters.setFocusAreas(Lists.newArrayList(new Camera.Area(focusRect, 1000)));

        if (meteringAreaSupported) {
            parameters.setMeteringAreas(Lists.newArrayList(new Camera.Area(meteringRect, 1000)));
        }

        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.autoFocus(this);
    }}
```

..... update

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    ...
    Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
    if (p.getMaxNumMeteringAreas() > 0) {
       this.meteringAreaSupported = true;
    }
    ...
}

/**
 * Convert touch position x:y to {@link Camera.Area} position -1000:-1000 to 1000:1000.
 */
private Rect calculateTapArea(float x, float y, float coefficient) {
    int areaSize = Float.valueOf(focusAreaSize * coefficient).intValue();

    int left = clamp((int) x - areaSize / 2, 0, getSurfaceView().getWidth() - areaSize);
    int top = clamp((int) y - areaSize / 2, 0, getSurfaceView().getHeight() - areaSize);

    RectF rectF = new RectF(left, top, left + areaSize, top + areaSize);
    matrix.mapRect(rectF);

    return new Rect(Math.round(rectF.left), Math.round(rectF.top), Math.round(rectF.right), Math.round(rectF.bottom));
}

private int clamp(int x, int min, int max) {
    if (x > max) {
        return max;
    }
    if (x < min) {
        return min;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: This seems interesting. Can you tell me what this code does? Focuses on the tapped object?

Comment: yup, Android setFocusArea and Auto Focus

Comment: Is this code part of any publicly available project on GitHub? Can you provide a full sample project?

Comment: The answer is literally copied and pasted from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460647/android-setfocusarea-and-auto-focus

Comment: Original question was about setting focus manually, this answer has copy-pasted code that sets auto-focus. Irrelevant to the question.